# Sorting values of a list inside a dataframe's column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as `df` :

```
   info      task                                               timestamp  
0  foo       ABC                                           ['2016-04-30']  
1  bar       DEF ['2016-01-31', '2015-06-30', '2016-06-30', '2016-08-31']  
2  bar       GHI               ['2015-12-31', '2016-08-31', '2016-05-31']  
3  foo       JKL                                           ['2017-03-31']  
4  foo       XYZ               ['2016-02-29', '2015-10-31', '2016-01-31']
```

i want to sort the dates inside the *timestamp* column. Please note the values within the timestamp column are in a list and of string types.

Desired output:

```
   info      task                                               timestamp  
0  foo       ABC                                           ['2016-04-30']  
1  bar       DEF ['2015-06-30', '2016-01-31', '2016-06-30', '2016-08-31']  
2  bar       GHI               ['2015-12-31', '2016-05-31', '2016-08-31']  
3  foo       JKL                                           ['2017-03-31']  
4  foo       XYZ               ['2015-10-31', '2016-01-31', '2016-02-29']
```

Comment: Storing data like this makes me cringe. Use a multi-index instead, it's so much easier. Makes sorting easier too.

Comment: At this point, it seems like all you can do is `df.timestamp.apply(sorted)` and nothing better *shudder*

Comment: how do you create df? I would say it is better to sort the timestamp list already before you create df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the obvious answer is to call `apply(sorted)` here, but I'm going to go on a tangent, because there's a fundamental flaw in how your data is structured.

Let's flatten your data first.

```
df

  info task                                         timestamp
0  foo  ABC                                      [2016-04-30]
1  bar  DEF  [2016-01-31, 2015-06-30, 2016-06-30, 2016-08-31]
2  bar  GHI              [2015-12-31, 2016-08-31, 2016-05-31]
3  foo  JKL                                      [2017-03-31]
4  foo  XYZ              [2016-02-29, 2015-10-31, 2016-01-31]
```

```
v = df.values
i = v[:, :-1].repeat(df.timestamp.str.len(), axis=0)
j = np.concatenate(v[:, -1]).reshape(-1, 1)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack((i, j)), columns=df.columns)

   info task   timestamp
0   foo  ABC  2016-04-30
1   bar  DEF  2016-01-31
2   bar  DEF  2015-06-30
3   bar  DEF  2016-06-30
4   bar  DEF  2016-08-31
5   bar  GHI  2015-12-31
6   bar  GHI  2016-08-31
7   bar  GHI  2016-05-31
8   foo  JKL  2017-03-31
9   foo  XYZ  2016-02-29
10  foo  XYZ  2015-10-31
11  foo  XYZ  2016-01-31
```

Now, `groupby` the first two columns and call `sort_values` -

```
df.groupby(['info', 'task'], sort=False)\
  .timestamp\
  .apply(pd.Series.sort_values)\
  .reset_index(level=[0, 1])

   info task   timestamp
0   foo  ABC  2016-04-30
2   bar  DEF  2015-06-30
1   bar  DEF  2016-01-31
3   bar  DEF  2016-06-30
4   bar  DEF  2016-08-31
5   bar  GHI  2015-12-31
7   bar  GHI  2016-05-31
6   bar  GHI  2016-08-31
8   foo  JKL  2017-03-31
10  foo  XYZ  2015-10-31
11  foo  XYZ  2016-01-31
9   foo  XYZ  2016-02-29
```

Which still needs an apply, but I'm willing to bet will be significantly faster, especially considering your other operations may not require an `apply` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

[Apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) allows you to invoke a function on values of Series:

```
df.timestamp.apply(sorted)
```

You can then assign the results back to the timestamp column.